# How can I call a template's private constructor from a different template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

for example:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<class U>
    MyClass<U> doSomething() { return MyClass<U>(); } //can't access private constructor
private:
    MyClass() {}
}
```

Template-voodoo answers and the like are acceptable. What's most important to me is that this class can create and return instances of itself with different template parameters, but that external code cannot call the particular constructor that it is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following in `MyClass`

```
template<typename Q> friend class MyClass;
```

`MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<float>` resolve to entirely different classes. They know nothing of eachother, and they can't access eachother's privates any more than 2 totally seperate classes. So, the solution is to have every instantiation of `MyClass` friend every other instantiation so they can all see eachother's privates as if they were the same class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that back in the recesses of my brain somewhere, I knew this. Seems impossible to keep all the nuances of C++ in one's head. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`friend` is your friend in this case, as every time you need restricted exceptions from privacy:

```
class MyClass {
     template <class U> friend class MyClass;
     ....
```